# Evitar mover los eventos entre días de la semana en FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
hola amigos tengo un problema con, fullcalendar.
necesito que los eventos no se puedan cambiar de dia , solo quiero que  se modifique el tiempo de la fecha actual.

Comment: Javier, bienvenido a SOes. Considera [edit] tu pregunta para incluir el código o las acciones que has implementado para resolver tu problema. Revisa el articulo de como incluir un [mcve] para mas información.

Comment: Puedes revisar la documentacion de full calendar hay varios métodos que te pueden ser util, te dejo el link https://fullcalendar.io/docs/

Comment: encontre la solucion gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```
        editable:true,                                                                         
        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {

            if ('<?php echo  $fechaActual; ?>' == event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD")) {

            var title = event.title;
            var start = event.start.format();
            var end = (event.end == null) ? start : event.end.format();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'modelos/TiempoTrabajo.php',
                data: 'accion=resetDate&start='+start+'&end='+end+'&eventid='+event.id,
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(response){
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
                    if(response.status != 'success')                
                    revertFunc();
                },
                error: function(e){                     
                    revertFunc();
                    alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
                }
            });
            }else{
                event.editable=false;
            }
        },
```

Comment: esta es la solución gracias pos sus aportes